# shebang in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, shell

I read somewhere that if I put `#! /usr/bin/python` in `testScript`, then running `./testScript` on the command line is equivalent to `/usr/bin/python testScript`

this makes sense to me since most scripting languages I know uses `#` for comments, so shebang will be picked up by `exec()` but ignored by the  actual interpreter

but now there's node, `#` is not in JavaScript syntax so I assume the interpreter has to do something special to skip the first `#!` line? Also out of curiosity is there another scripting language that doesn't use `#` for comments?

Comment: Asking "which languages do/don't" is probably Too Broad. And yes, Node (or whatever) needs to have a special clause to skip/ignore such line as it's indeed invalid JavaScript.

Comment: ah yes I just confirmed, if I add `#! confusedDev`(invalid javaScript) to a node script, I can still run it just fine on the command line with `node testScript`. @user2864740 I was thinking there should not be pretty small amount of scripting languages that doesn't use `#`, if they are old languages I probably would have heard of them and if they are new they probably are designed with `#!` in mind. Do you know any?

Comment: If JS is a "Scripting Language" per this question, then so is PHP. And PHP uses `//` style comments. Also, "LISP"s usually use `;`.

Comment: I only consider languages that are designed to be used interactively - ie. for running programs or other shell purposes - "scripting languages": Sh+friends, PowerShell, etc.

Comment: tldr; there are *many* languages that executed "directly from source without a required intermediate compilation phase" - this just means they are "non compiled" or "optionally compiled".

Comment: You're right, `#!` is not a valid syntax in Javascript. It's pretty clear it does not make much sense within the historical running context of a Javascript program like a web browser. And obviously, this is not part of the ecmascript specification.

Since Nodejs brings Javascript to the server side, the nodejs interpreter have to somehow deal with the shebang line.

If we look at the source code, we can find a function [`stripShebang()`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/9c6f6b0633ef4009cc04cfff5efb29c23ef5fc2b/lib/internal/module.js#L54) who find and slice that specific line.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Syntax has been introduced in ecmascript in the TC39 meeting, this means you can run js code by on your terminal by typing `./filename.js`
Read more about the new features on JavaScript [here](https://github.com/tc39/notes/tree/main/meetings/2023-03)

Comment: Downvoted because this question is about Node, which has always supported the shebang; not ECMAScript.